# Alternative PHP function to DateInterval DateTime::diff ( DateTime $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = false ] )

Tags: php, function

Have you got an equivalent function to `DateInterval DateTime::diff ( DateTime $datetime2 [, bool $absolute = false ] )`?

This is not available in previous version then 5.3.0.

Comment: Since you've asked in a comment to a now deleted answer "Is the code of that function free?": Yes, see http://svn.php.net/viewvc/php/php-src/trunk/ext/date/

Comment: How would you being using the difference?  For example are you using it to see if one date is greater by X days/months/years than the other?

Answer (score 0):

You can just convert both DateTimes to a unix timestamp and subtract those :) The result is the number of seconds difference.